# HTML capture inputs from USB Arduino

Tags: html, usb, arduino

Can we use HTML to capture the input from USB Arduino?

I just got an [Arduino Duemilanove](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardDuemilanove). My plan is to write a [Processing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processing_%28programming_language%29) program on the Arduino, and then read the switch input from A0 using HTML on a normal browser.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I've done close to this is using a USB device as a "keyboard wedge" where the data comes in as if it were typed. You can capture the "keystrokes" in a standard HTML input.

The only other idea would to have it simulate mouse buttons. Other than that, there's not a heck of a lot of external I/O that can be handled in a browser without writing a custom plug-in.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the solution you're looking for is to create a web server (LAMP stack, node.js, etc) with a perl, PHP, etc cgi-script that reads the output from the arduino from a serial connection.

As mentioned by Diodeus, there's no way to do this with just HTML as HTML is not a programming language.  That's why you need the server backend to generate dynamic content based off some information.  In the case of google it's a database.  In your case it's most likely serial data.